# Number Theory Lemma About Linear Congruence (Explanation Needed)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

I was reading Elementary Number Theory Second Edition by Dudley Underwood, and I came across what appeared to me to be a contradiction in chapter/section 5.

The book says: If one integer satisfies $ax \equiv b $ (mod m) $\implies $ there are infinitley many

Then the book says: if gcd$(a,m) = 1$, then $ax \equiv b $ (mod m) has exactly one solution.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Presumably he means there is exactly one solution mod $m$.

Comment: Oh, so he means there is only one $b$?

Comment: No, only one $x$, namely the residue class of $a^{-1}b$. Note that $a$ is invertible mod $m$ since $(a,m)=1$.

Comment: So, only one residue class of $x$?

Comment: There are infinitely many *integer* solutions, all congruent to the unique solution $\!\pmod{\! m}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcd$(a,m)=1$, then $ax≡b$ $\pmod m$ has exactly one solution $x$ < $m$. There are infinitely many solutions, and each one is congruent to $x \pmod m$.

Comment: So the solution is the least residue (mod $m$). In other words the remainder of any $x$ - that makes the equation true - divided by $m$?

Comment: Yes, there is only one solution (residue) $x$ $\pmod m$ since the polynomial degree is 1. (Your book should explain that somewhere else.)